# The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'PPR_Status_Detailed'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oledb

[database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr7iJ.png)

I am trying to upload excel spreadsheet to sql database through c# asp.net web page.
I keep getting the error: "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'PPR_Status_Detailed', Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly." I dont understand why , i have changed my connection string and sheet name as but still get this error . when i open the excel file and then try to upload it , it says "External Table not in expected format" . i am using .xls & .xlxs files

it fails at OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();

code:

```
> public partial class Upload : System.Web.UI.Page {
>     string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostbankConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
> 
>     }
> 
>    public void importdatafromexcel(string excelfilepath)
>         {
>             //declare variables - edit these based on your particular situation
>             string ssqltable = "PPRS";
>             // make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if have different
>             string myexceldataquery = "Select * FROM [PPR_Status_Detailed]";
>             try
>             {
>                 //create our connection strings
>                 string sexcelconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelfilepath +
> ";Extended Properties=" + "\"excel 12.0;hdr=yes;\"";
> 
>                 string sclearsql = "TRUNCATE TABLE " + ssqltable;
>                 SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
>                 SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
>                 sqlconn.Open();
>                 sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>               
>                 //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
>                 OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
>                 OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
>                 oledbconn.Open();
>                 OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
> 
>                 SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnString);
>                 bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
>                 //Mapping Table column    
> 
>                 bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Task ID","[Task_ID]");
>                 bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PPR Caption", "[PPR_Caption]");
>                 bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Project Start Date", "[Project_StartDate]");
>                 bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Project End Date", "[Project_EndDate]");
>                 bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Current Task", "[Current_Task]");
>                 bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User", "[User]");
>        
> 
> 
>                 sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>                 while (dr.Read())
>                 {
>                     bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
>                 }
> 
>                 oledbconn.Close();
>                 sqlconn.Close();
>              
>             }
> 
>             catch (Exception)
>             {
>                 //handle exception
>             }
>         }
>  
> 
>    }
> 
>    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
>        string CurrentFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
>        importdatafromexcel(CurrentFilePath);     } }
```

Comment: Do you know what line it is failing on? Excel Sheets are always with a $ at the end so your SQL should be Select * From [PPR_Status_Detailed$]

Comment: i added the $ sign and now my error says The given ColumnName 'Task ID' does not match up with any column in data source." all my columns match and the datatype for the columns in the database is nvarchar(max) –

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :-

```
OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Try this :-

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = oledbconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbcmd);
sda.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

To read the excel name correctly please use below code:-

```
OleDbConn.Open();
DataTable dt = OleDbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string tableName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
OleDbCommand OleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]" , OleDbConn);
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: how do i use the dataset in   :  sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }

Comment: You don't need sqlcmd.executenonquery(). You can simply afteer column mappings use:- bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr); That's All. :)

Comment: i tried your solution now my error is "The given ColumnName 'Task ID' does not match up with any column in data source." all my columns match and the datatype for the columns in the database is nvarchar(max)

Comment: Please find the code for reading excel sheet name correctly and also make sure your column matches with that in your excel file.

Comment: they all match i double checked them however the error still remains, it fails at       bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);

Comment: Please share your new code. Also your database table structure.

Comment: I've added the database in the link database design

Comment: Your error says that there's mismatch between column name in excel file and source column described in Bulk copy column mappings.

Comment: Pass DataTable object in bulk server writeToServer function and not OleDbDataReader  object.